# for this statement String a="MAM"+"BCD"+"EFG"+"GFE"; How many objects will be created? (I am confused is it created 4 or 5 or 7)

Tags: string

for this statement

```
String a="MAM"+"BCD"+"EFG"+"GFE";
```

How many objects will be created? (I am confused is it created 4 or 5 or 7)

Comment: Well, it probably won't matter, but what language?

Answer (score 1):

Most smart compilers will realize that concatenated string constants can be concatenated at compile time. If your compiler chooses to make that optimization, the answer is one.

Otherwise, you have each of your literal strings, plus one for each concatenation. Without the optimization, the answer is 7 because you have 4 strings and 3 `+`es.

Comment: Many compilers will optimize a bunch of `+`es to calls to StringBuilder.Append, or similar. In that case, it would be 6: 4 strings, 1 StringBuilder, and 1 result String.

Comment: If you're talking about Java, the compiler is *required* to concatenate the strings at compile time: it's specified in the JLS.

Comment: @EJP: Java wasn't specified, so I tried to provide a generic answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about Java, the answer is one, at compile time, as specified in the JLS.

If you're not, the question is unanswerable as posed.

Answer (score 0):

Only one object will be created. In this case because the plus sign is used to concatenate "string literals". :)

Comment: No, it is because the plus sign is being used *to concatenate string literals.*